# how to export data that contain both number and text columns to csv file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a dataset containing one column of datestring, one column of model name (in char format), and a bunch of numerical data columns. How can i export them into csv file? The output file i want is that first it has two rows of headers and units and then comes to my dataset. Is this doable? Thanks.
My old code is like this that works well only for export numerical data. But now i have text column to add in, so i don't know how to modify it.

```
f=fopen('filename.csv','w');
fprintf(f,'hearders\n units\n');
fclose(f);
dlmwrite('filename.csv',dataset,'-append','precison','%.8f');
```

Comment: what is the class of  `dataset` (a cell, a struct)?

Comment: now it's a cell.1*14 cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can continue with `fprintf`, something like:

```
f=fopen('filename.csv','w');
fprintf(f,'hearders\n units\n');
formatspec = '%s ... %.8f %6.2f %12.8f %whatever ... \n';
fprintf(f,formatspec,dataset{:});
fclose(f);
```

you'll need to edit the format of the 3rd line according to the data types in each cell row...
play with `fprintf(formatSpec,dataset{:})` option to print to screen to see that you got it right.

Comment: Thank you natan, this gives me an idea to modify my code and it's working very well now.